# Caesar cipher in C. My plaintext won't shift and the cipher text outcome is identical to it

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong yet, but while I continue to figure it out, I'd love to get some input from others w/ experience. The goal is to cipher the plaintext using a key provided at the command line. I can't wrap my head around why my ciphertext comes out the same as my plaintext. I seem to have figured out case preserving and wrapping around the alphabet, but I'm stuck with this part. Included libraries: stdio.h, stdlib.h, string.h.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int e = 0;
    string k;
    string p;
    int key;

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        k = argv[1];
    }
    else
    {
        e++;
        printf("Error: %i\n", e);
    }
    key = atoi(argv[1]);

    p = get_string("plaintext: ");

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(p); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (p[n] >= 'a' && p[n] <= 'z')
        {
            p[n] = (p[i] + key - 'a') % 26 + 'a';
        }
        else if (p[n] >= 'A' && p[n] <= 'Z')
        {
            p[n] = (p[i] + key - 'A') % 26 + 'A';
        }
    }
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Bugs:
1) You're using p[n] instead of p[i]
2) The top section with k and e serves no purpose.

Style:
1) Your variables need better (more descriptive) names.

Aside from the bug, the algorithm looks correct.  As an improvement, having it take key / input file / output file as command line arguments would be more useful for most purposes.  Alternately, having it take just the key as an argument, accepting input without a prompt (piped in) and outputting just the encrypted text (for piping out) would also work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bugs and for providing the helpful suggestions. This was part of instructions for a course problem set, so I was following their requirements. The e variable was to return an error. I can see that I may be declaring it in the wrong order perhaps. Much appreciated!